# threejs Creating a grid from triangles

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to create a grid using the following code. The reason is I would like the grid this way is to have the face to be colored and then change the color when I parse in the x,y coordinates. But I get a "*draw array attempt to get access out of bound arrays*" error.

```
for (var i = 0, j = 0, k = -halfSize; i <= divisions; i++, k += step) {

    vertices.push(-halfSize, 0, k, halfSize, 0, k);
    vertices.push(k, 0, -halfSize, k, 0, halfSize);
    var colorg = new THREE.Color("rgb(255, 0, 0)");
    colorg.toArray( colors, j ); j += 3;
        colorg.toArray( colors, j ); j += 3;
        colorg.toArray( colors, j ); j += 3;
        colorg.toArray( colors, j ); j += 3;

  }
  var vertices32 = new Float32Array(vertices);
  var colors32 = new Float32Array(colors);


  geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices32, 3 ));
  geometry.addAttribute('normal', new THREE.BufferAttribute(normals, 3));
  geometry.addAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(colors32, 3));
  //fgeometry.addAttribute('uv', new THREE.BufferAttribute(uvs, 2));

  // optional
  geometry.computeBoundingBox();
  geometry.computeBoundingSphere();

  // set the normals
  geometry.computeVertexNormals(); // computed vertex normals are orthogonal to the face for non-indexed BufferGeometry

  // material
  var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff,
    shading: THREE.FlatShading,
    vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
  });

  // mesh
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [BufferGeometry.toNonIndexed](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/BufferGeometry.toNonIndexed)? In this way you can create a normal `PlaneBufferGeometry` and turn it into a non-indexed geometry. Each face has now unique vertices.

```
let geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry();
geometry = geometry.toNonIndexed();
```

After that, you just add the color attribute to the geometry. Full example:

https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/4230/